# matplotlib.pyplot: align axes labels when using a colorbar for each subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, axes

**The Problem:** I am using matplotlib to create a figure with multiple subplots. Each subplot has both x- and y-axis labels, and may also have its own colorbar.

By default, axis labels are placed next to the tick marks (Figure 1, left). However, I want the y-axis labels to vertically align (Figure 1, right). I am using `fig.align_labels()` to do this.

*Figure 1:*
[image: Figure 1]

I want to include colorbars on each subplot (Figure 2, left). However, when I use `fig.align_labels()`, the axis labels are simply collapsed onto the same position (Figure 2, right).

*Figure 2:*
[image: Figure 2]

**The Question:** How can we align the y-axis labels when colorbars are used?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np

x = np.array(np.arange(5))
y = [np.random.uniform(0.5,2,5)*np.random.random(5)+100,   # <-- 'Long' tick labels
    np.random.uniform(0.5,2,5)*np.random.random(5)+100,    # <-- 'Long' tick labels
    np.random.uniform(0.5,2,5)*np.random.random(5),        # <-- 'Short' tick labels
    np.random.uniform(0.5,2,5)*np.random.random(5)]        # <-- 'Short' tick labels

fig = plt.figure()

for plotnum,yvals in enumerate(y):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,plotnum+1)
    sc = ax.scatter(x,yvals,c=yvals)
    fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax)

    ax.set(ylabel=f'Y Values {plotnum}', xlabel=f'X Values {plotnum}')
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.1f}')) 

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.8, hspace=0.6)
fig.align_labels()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a bug in `align_labels`, which apparently was never tested with colorbars.  Did you have the bandwidth to open an issue at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most optimal way to handle this in your code is to add a line to the loop process.

```
fig = plt.figure()

for plotnum,yvals in enumerate(y):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,plotnum+1)
    sc = ax.scatter(x,yvals,c=yvals)
    fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax)
    ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.4, 0.5) # update
    ax.set_ylabel(f'Y Values {plotnum}')
    ax.set_xlabel(f'X Values {plotnum}')
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.1f}')) 

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.8, hspace=0.6)
#fig.align_ylabels()

plt.show()
```

[image]